# Does an enclosing Wall of Stone with a tiny gap provide a saving throw to escape the area?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wall

The [Wall of Stone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-stone) spell creates a contiguous wall. If the wall would surround a creature, the creature gets a saving throw to avoid getting trapped:

> If a creature would be surrounded on all sides by the wall (or the wall and another solid surface), that creature can make a Dexterity saving throw. On a success, it can use its Reaction to move up to its speed so that it is no longer enclosed by the wall.

If I shape the Wall of Stone around a creature but leave out a tiny gap (say, less than 1-inch wide), would that forfeit the saving throw because the wall doesn't fully surround the creature?

If the tiny gap is not enough, how large does it have to be for the saving throw to be forfeit?

Answer (score 13):

### The gap needs to leave the option of escaping the "enclosure."

This gap size will vary depending on the creature. Narratively it is comfortable
to handwave that the creature can leave the "enclosure" deliberately without specifying its exact measurements.

Emphasis mine:

> **it can** use its Reaction to move up to its speed **so that it is no
> longer enclosed** by the wall.

If it cannot leave the enclosure created by the walls via regular movement, it will have to make a saving throw. Because you want to prevent the saving throw, you will have to create the wall in a manner that makes the enclosure exit-able by the creature at any time via regular movement.

Comment: Of course if the only way out is over the edge of a cliff that is not your problem anymore and satisfies the spells requirements ;)